# App engine deployment down with "The Node.js binary could not be verified"

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, deployment

My app engine deployment (flexible environment, node js 12) has suddenly started failing, seemingly due to an issue with node js on the google side.

Build output here:

```
Step #1: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor@sha256:f87c11770a4d3ed33436508d206c584812cd656e6ed08eda1cff5c1ee44f5870
Step #1: [36mINFO[0m[0000] Removing ignored files from build context: [node_modules .dockerignore Dockerfile npm-debug.log yarn-error.log .git .hg .svn app.yaml]
Step #1: [36mINFO[0m[0004] Downloading base image gcr.io/google-appengine/nodejs@sha256:ef8be7b4dc77c3e71fbc85ca88186b13214af8f83b8baecc65e8ed85bb904ad5
Step #1: [36mINFO[0m[0019] Taking snapshot of full filesystem...
Step #1: [36mINFO[0m[0035] Using files from context: [/workspace]
Step #1: [36mINFO[0m[0036] COPY . /app/
Step #1: [36mINFO[0m[0036] Taking snapshot of files...
Step #1: [36mINFO[0m[0037] RUN /usr/local/bin/install_node '>=12.0.0'
Step #1: [36mINFO[0m[0037] cmd: /bin/sh
Step #1: [36mINFO[0m[0037] args: [-c /usr/local/bin/install_node '>=12.0.0']
Step #1:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Step #1:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 32.1M  100 32.1M    0     0  66.9M      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 66.8M
Step #1:   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
Step #1:                                  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  3838  100  3838    0     0  23116      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 23260
Step #1: gpg: Signature made Tue Sep 8 15:43:07 2020 UTC using RSA key ID C17AB93C gpg: Can't check signature: public key not found
Step #1: The Node.js binary could not be verified.
Step #1: This means it may not be an officially released Node.js binary
Step #1: or may have been tampered with.
Step #1:
Step #1: Aborting the installation.
Step #1:
Step #1: The installation can be forced using the --ignore-verification-failure
Step #1: flag. However, it is strongly recommended that you install a version
Step #1: of Node.js that can be verified.
Step #1:
Step #1: Node installation failed: /opt/gcp/runtime/bootstrap_node exited with a non-zero exit code: 1
Step #1: error building image: error building stage: waiting for process to exit: exit status 1
Finished Step #1
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor@sha256:f87c11770a4d3ed33436508d206c584812cd656e6ed08eda1cff5c1ee44f5870" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Is anybody else seeing this issue?

Thanks

Chris

Comment: I experience the same error. any progress so far?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In our case, the thing was that App Engine installed Node 14.10.0 because we had `"node": "14.x"` in the `package.json`. Seems like the latest release has some issues.

I fixed deploy by changing the engine to a fixed version:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "14.9"
}
```

If you are using 12.x - try some of the previous version that worked.

Comment: if you are using a flex environment, then you cannot specify the node version

Comment: @coderman Node version can be set in package.json as mentioned in my answer. Please take a look at official docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/nodejs/runtime#nodejs_version

Comment: I tried 14.x, 14.12.0, 14.12 which all failed then 14.9 worked. Seems like random bs.

Comment: Note to those people changing from the GAE standard environment to the flex environment, be very wary of costs - the flex environment by default keeps 1 instance running *permanently* and along with it the cost of a cpu running 24x7! I found out the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

The latest that works is 14.16.0. Add the following in your `package.json`

```
...
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.16.0"
  },
...
```

Then deploy with `gcloud app deploy`. The GCP issue to follow is https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docker/issues/214

Answer (score 0):

This happens quite often whenever a new Nodejs version is released as GAE builder "is not entirely backwards compatible between minor version upgrades" (Source: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-docker/issues/214#issuecomment-1276728834)

The **fix/solution** would be to **pin down the last version that worked** (in most cases, the **2nd most recent that was released**: https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/). You will most likely notice that a nodejs version was released around the time your build started failing.